# php pdo search column array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

table name - animationmaster

column -  animationdate ,type= varchar

column -  animationno ,type= varchar

data in each column are like below..

animationno = 300,301

animationdate  =  300 - 23-03-2015,301- 23-04-2015

When user search 300  then it display output 300 - 23-03-2015 from animationdate

When user search 301 then it display output  301- 23-04-2015 from animationdate

My mean is if user hit 300 then it match in animationdate  column and get values of 300 upto comma only.

Please, help to get solution for this array search

```
<?php   
$q = $_GET['q'];
$city = $database->getRows("SELECT animationdate  FROM animationmaster WHERE animationno = :animationno ", array(':animationno '=>"$q"));  
$info = array();
foreach($city as $row)
{       
    $generat = $row['animationdate'];           
    
    $info[] = array('date' =>$generat);
}
echo json_encode($info);
?>
```

Comment: What you really expect to do with this value? How can user choose each available value? Your question is unclear for what you need.

Comment: Why not split that data into two columns so you can do a proper select on it?